# Is there an effective way to clean up shattered glass from a floor?

Tags: cleaning, safety, glass, house-cleaning

Whenever I try to clean up broken glass, I always find small pieces even after cleaning it up several times. Is there a way to get rid of broken glass?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Broken glass pieces are sometimes scattered to an invisible size. It is important to clean these scattered and splashed broken glass in the best way possible. Otherwise, another accident or injury may result.

First the large pieces are collected by hand and then the **vacuum cleaner** will pull all the glass pieces. **Cotton** can be used for broken glass that does not require a vacuum cleaner. When a piece of torn cotton is wetted with water and swept around the broken area, it will collect the glass shards that are difficult to see with the eye. The same process can be done with **tape**. By tearing a piece of tape and moving it over the ground, the broken pieces can be collected on the belt.

Answer (score 4):

@Mordecai's answer has all the right methods for picking up the glass, all I would add is that a bright torch really helps to make shards of glass more visible on the floor. You need to keep moving the torch around, and it also helps if someone else stands back from the area and shines the torch over while you look; this creates lower angles that you can't achieve on your own.

Another little trick that can be helpful is to 1) gather all of the pieces together as you pick them up, maybe on a piece of paper, 2) Get another glass of the same type (if you have one) and WEIGH it on kitchen scales 3) check that the pieces you have collected are the same weight as the "control".

I can tell you for a fact that I have spent 10 or 15 minutes picking up pieces of glass of 2 or 3mm in length, only to suddenly realise that there's a huge, dangerous chunk just sitting there waiting to be stood on. The weight discrepancy will definitely highlight this situation before it harms anyone.

Answer (score 3):

A piece of bread pressed onto the glass or on the spot where you think glass may be.